# Can't get Angularjs to update view when model updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, model

I am an Angular newbie and I'm stuck.  I have some code on jsbin.com --->(http://jsbin.com/ratageza/7/edit?html,js,output)

It's not pretty but it's showing essentially what I am doing.
In my real code I am using $http.get calls a RESTful backend to load data from a database, and $http.post calls to add to the database.  All works fine as far as the database fetches and updates. But after I create a new object using the "Create" form, if I click "List All" my tournaments object is not updated.

I'm confused about whether I would need $apply after the $http.post call?  I've tried using it but am either using it wrong or that's not my problem here.  I've looked all around stackoverflow and can't seem to find the answer to my problem.

If anybody can see what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the slight changes I made here: http://jsbin.com/ratageza/8/edit?html,js,output

The change is how you define your controller usage.  You use TournamentController in two different places which actually gives you two instances of that controller with two separate, isolated scopes.  Your List All view was bound to one instance while the Create view was bound to a completely different instance.

Also, your question about $apply.  As a general rule, you should very seldom have to use $apply and you should NEVER use it in a controller as it's not safe to use there.  Directives are really the only safe place to use $apply and even there it should only be used if data is being modified outside the scope of angular.  The order in which things are processed, you find that if you use $scope.$apply() in a controller, you will frequently get exceptions about already being in a digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/ratageza/10/edit  this works.

It's not a $apply or $diget issue. Because you put TournamentController into to part of views. One is create and the other one is to show. That makes a different copy of $scope.tournament;

So I add a div to wrapper the Form and the table. Put the controller to it. Remove the form and table controller.

Hope this can solve your problem. :)